# File executable only for users in a certain group in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just want to know how to make a file executable only for certain group.

I have a file `/bin/ping` with this permissions

```
rwxr-xr-x root root 34248 oct 14 2010 /bin/ping
```

How do I make it only executable for users of a group called "friends", for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the group "friends" already exist, you can change group by

```
chown root:friends /bin/ping
```

and then make it exucutable for that group by

```
chmod g+x /bin/ping
```

Comment: You'll need to add root to the group, otherwise it is undefined by the [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/chgrp.html) standard. See "APPLICATION USAGE"

Answer (score 2):

I'd use ACL for this. First revoke permissions for everyone else with standard unix permissions

```
chmod 754 /bin/ping
```

then set rule for your group

```
setfacl -m "g:friends:r-x" /bin/ping
```

Comment: I like this answer, even though I find ACL's are often easy to forget when backing up with files. Also, how does this actually prevent other users from executing the file? Don't you have to revoke execution for everyone else first?

Comment: Ah yes he needs to revoke the permissions first then do ACL. ACLs are additive to standard unix permissions. Thanks, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

The original permissions are:

```
rwxr-xr-x root root 34248 oct 14 2010 /bin/ping
```

Which means:

1. root can read+write+execute (rwx)
2. everyone in root group can read+execute (r-x)
3. everyone else can read+execute (the last 'r-x' triplet)

So to only allow the "friends" group to execute it, you have to do 2 things:

2. Change the group to friends (`chgrp friends /bin/ping`)
3. Prevent "everyone else" from executing (`chmod o-x` - the "o" stands for "other")

So that the listing would look like this

```
rwxr-xr-- root friends 34248 oct 14 2010 /bin/ping
```

It's best to always test things like this, just to be sure (by switching to another user and making sure you get an error).